# rewrite comand like a [key=value] using xparse or latex3 syntax

Tags: macros, font-encodings, xparse

I've written a macro to use some command like a `ltxdoc` (\oarg,\meta,\marg) without using the `textcomp` and `ltxdoc`to colorate and decide the font style with which the angle, brackets and text in command. 
I would like to write the command of the form:

```
\mycomand[key=value]{...}
```

But it has been difficult to me because of the selection of sources font for typewrite and roman.
This is the file (MWE)

```
% 2015-29-04
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}%
\usepackage{libertine}%
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{listings}
% Font used for \textangle in \ttfamily
\DeclareFontEncoding{TS1}{}{}
\DeclareFontSubstitution{TS1}{cmr}{m}{n}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\ttlangle}{TS1}{60}
\DeclareTextSymbol{\ttrangle}{TS1}{62}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ttlangle}{TS1}
\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ttrangle}{TS1}
% adapted from doc.dtx    
\providecommand\meta[1]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\ttlangle\/}\ignorespaces{\normalfont\itshape #1\/}{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{TS1}\selectfont\/\ttrangle}} % close
% adapted from ltxdoc.dtx
\providecommand\marg[1]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\{\ignorespaces}\normalfont\meta{#1}\ignorespaces{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont\}\ignorespaces}} % close
\providecommand\oarg[1]{{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont [}\normalfont\meta{#1}{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontencoding{T1}\selectfont ]\ignorespaces}} % close
\begin{document}
\noindent
ROMAN

\textlangle\emph{meta}\textrangle \par
[\textlangle\emph{oarg}\textrangle] \par
\{\textlangle\emph{marg}\textrangle\} \par

\noindent
TYPEWRITE 

\meta{meta} \par
\oarg{oarg} \par
\marg{marg} \par

\let\us\textunderscore
\newcommand\placeholder[1]%
{%
    \bgroup
        \normalfont\upshape\color{RubineRed}%
        \textlangle{\itshape #1\/}\textrangle%
    \egroup
}

\lstset
{%
    basicstyle  = \ttfamily,
        escapeinside={<}{>},%
}

\noindent
TEST USING ROMAN 
\begin{lstlisting}
for i= <\placeholder{first\us{}value}>:<\placeholder{last\us{}value}>
    % do stuff
end
\end{lstlisting}

\noindent
TEST USING TYPEWRITER
\begin{lstlisting}
for i= <\meta{first\us{}value}>:<\meta{last\us{}value}>
    % do stuff
end
\end{lstlisting}

TRY

\begin{lstlisting}
\mymeta[type=<\meta{tt,rm}>,cf=<\meta{color font}>,ac=<\meta{angle color}>]{ ... }
\myoarg[type=<\meta{tt,rm}>,cf=<\meta{color font}>,ac=<\meta{angle color}>,sbc=<\meta{square brackets color}>]{ ... }
\mymarg[type=<\meta{tt,rm}>,cf=<\meta{color font}>,ac=<\meta{angle color}>,cbc=<\meta{curly braces color}>]{ ... }
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

My idea would be to let the default typewrite font and everything in black color.

**Edit:**
Attempt to define the keys:

```
type= text font (tt or rm) (default tt)
cf  = color font (default black)
ac  = angle color (default black)
sbc = square brackets color (default black)
cbc = curly braces color (default black)
```

And command(s)

```
% use \meta
\mymeta[type=tt,cf=red,ac=green}]{ ... }
% use \oarg
\myoarg[type=tt,cf=red,ac=green,sbc=blue]{ ... }
% use \marg
\mymarg[type=tt,cf=red,ac=green,cbc=blue]{ ... }
```

Thankful in advance.

Comment: What do you want to specify with the keys? The description you give in the last lines doesn't tell much.

Comment: @egreg: thanks for the reply , I edited the post to clarify the idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a possible implementation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
%\usepackage{libertine}
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% user level commands
\NewDocumentCommand{\meta}{O{}m}
 {
  \pablo_meta_generic:Nnn \pablo_meta:n { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\marg}{O{}m}
 {
  \pablo_meta_generic:Nnn \pablo_marg:n { #1 } { #2 }
 }
\NewDocumentCommand{\oarg}{O{}m}
 {
  \pablo_meta_generic:Nnn \pablo_oarg:n { #1 } { #2 }
 }

% variables and keys
\tl_new:N \l_pablo_meta_font_tl

\keys_define:nn { pablo/meta }
 {
  type .choice:,
  type / tt .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_pablo_meta_font_tl { \ttfamily },
  type / rm .code:n = \tl_set:Nn \l_pablo_meta_font_tl { \rmfamily },
  type .initial:n = tt,
  cf .tl_set:N = \l_pablo_meta_color_tl,
  cf .initial:n = black,
  ac .tl_set:N = \l_pablo_meta_anglecolor_tl,
  ac .initial:n = black,
  sbc .tl_set:N = \l_pablo_meta_brackcolor_tl,
  sbc .initial:n = black,
  cbc .tl_set:N = \l_pablo_meta_bracecolor_tl,
  cbc .initial:n = black,
 }


% internal commands
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta_generic:Nnn #1 #2 #3
 {
  \group_begin:
  \keys_set:nn { pablo/meta } { #2 }
  \color{ \l_pablo_meta_color_tl }
  \l_pablo_meta_font_tl
  #1 { #3 } % #1 is \pablo_meta:n, \pablo_marg:n or \pablo_oarg:n
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta:n #1
 {
  \pablo_meta_angle:n { \textlangle }
  \pablo_meta_meta:n { #1 }
  \pablo_meta_angle:n { \textrangle }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_marg:n #1
 {
  \pablo_meta_brace:n { \textbraceleft }
  \pablo_meta:n { #1 }
  \pablo_meta_brace:n { \textbraceright }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_oarg:n #1
 {
  \pablo_meta_brack:n { [ }
  \pablo_meta:n { #1 }
  \pablo_meta_brack:n { ] }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta_meta:n #1
 {
  \textnormal{\textit{#1}}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta_angle:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \fontfamily{cmr}\selectfont
  \textcolor{\l_pablo_meta_anglecolor_tl}{#1}
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta_brace:n #1
 {
  \group_begin:
  \color{\l_pablo_meta_bracecolor_tl}
  #1
  \group_end:
 }
\cs_new_protected:Npn \pablo_meta_brack:n #1
 {
  \textcolor{\l_pablo_meta_brackcolor_tl}{#1}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

\noindent
\meta{something}\\
\marg{mandatory argument}\\
\oarg{optional argument}

\noindent
\meta[cf=red,ac=green]{something}\\
\marg[type=rm,cbc=red]{mandatory argument}\\
\oarg[type=rm,sbc=blue]{optional argument}

\end{document}
\noindent
\meta{something}\\
\marg{mandatory argument}\\
\oarg{optional argument}

\noindent
\meta{something}\\
\marg{mandatory argument}\\
\oarg{optional argument}

\noindent
\meta{something}\\
\marg{mandatory argument}\\
\oarg{optional argument}

\end{document}
```

I commented out `libertine` because the difference between Roman and monospaced fonts is better seen with Computer Modern.

[image]

Note that `\meta`, `\marg` and `\oarg` are defined in terms of a generic command that does the setting of the keys and calls the appropriate internal command. All items are defined with a particular macro, so to achieve uniformity.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I trying not to use the `textcomp` package, i need if the option tt load `{ }` , `[]` load from typewrite font and the symbol `\textlangle` and `\textrangle` from `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ttlangle}{TS1}` and `\DeclareTextSymbolDefault{\ttrangle}{TS1}` . Is it possible to do this ?. Loading `tetcomp` take \textlangle`and \textrangle`direct from font if available (libertine for example) and does not look good when you want to write in a context verbatim. Saludos

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL With my code the angle brackets are taken from Computer Modern.

Comment: Thank you so much , is exactly what I wanted, works perfectly whit angle braquets, ...Will it work on luatex and xetex too?

Comment: @PabloGonzálezL You'd have just to modify the definition of the angle brackets.

Comment: ok , that would be another question. thanks for everything.